# Swipe action on Application screens

Tags: android, navigation, swipe-gesture

I need a common swipe gesture for my application. How it can be possible.

Suppose i have a app with two Activity and whenever i swipe(left/right) over any of the screen , it will do any action .

But i don't want to attach swipe gesture separately in those activity. I need a common place to attach it. (Because i may have many screens and fragments)

Comment: visit this   http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118

Comment: thanks @Harshad, This type of Demo i have used. But if you have many activities , how to use same swipe gesture at a common place because i can't attach it seperately in my 20-30 Activities and 10-20 fragments

Comment: Visit this for http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2262133&seqNum=3

Comment: Create Seperate class and implement in All Activity..